# Gps updates in background for long time

Tags: android, background, gps, location, location-services

I have implemented a foreground service to get GPS updates for longer runs, like 3 hours, when the app is in background. It is our business requirement. But the app stops getting updates after a few minutes. I see the "location icon" on top bar go disappear, even though my foreground service notification is still there.

I have also excluded my app from Battery Optimization list from the settings, so that Android doesn't kill my app. It helps to keep gps updates alive for about half an hour only, then again the location icon goes away and i stop getting gps updates.

What can I do to keep it always ON?

Comment: Related: [https://dontkillmyapp.com/](https://dontkillmyapp.com/)

Comment: You can start that service by separate process by adding  `android:process=":FusedLocationService"` in your `Service` component in `manifest.xml`. I had done this and work in most of the device except some of the manufactures like Honor and other because they customized Android AOSP for better user experience.

Comment: @MD ok i'll try this

Comment: @MD thanks, this seems to be working. You put your answer, so that i can accepts

Comment: Wow glad to hear that. Let me post as answer so it will help to others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this answer based on my short comment and OP request

You can start that **service** by separate process by adding `android:process=":FusedLocationService"` in your Service component in **manifest.xml**.

I had done this and work in most of the device except some of the manufactures like Honor and other because they customized Android AOSP for better user experience

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Though it was a big hassle to handle separate process thing, all that inter-process communications..

Comment: Do u know why this works? i would like to know that too

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan As per my knowledge If you make separate service then it may be not depend on your main app process and also it uses resources separately from your main app. So even if  your main app process get kill this separate service never effect.

Comment: hm. i was wondering y the separate process is not killed. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan In most of the devices worked well but expect some of the devices like Honor and etc might not work

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html

Apart form this you can use JobScheduler to fetch location data after a particular interval (approx 15 mins) 
You can build logic a/c to OS version as well.

And while fetching the location use FLP (FusedLocationProvider)

Hope this will help, But after all this depend on Mobile brand(like ONE PLUS) you will face the issues. You need to handle these scenario as well.

Comment: I need gps location every 5 seconds. If I use FPL every 5 seconds, this wont get new location from GPS, right? this will just tell me the last best location.

Comment: Yes correct, FPL will always show you last location. After API 28 it is very difficult to achieve. There is a project on Github it's name is GpsTracker serach that may that code will give you some idea.
check this as well
https://github.com/smtrz/GPSTracker-Android